# symfony2 throws "A Token was not found in the SecurityContext" with bots

Tags: php, security, symfony, exception, token

In my symfony2 application, I built an exception listener which sends me an email when an exception occurs (I filtered out 404 and made sure it would not throw an email more than one a day for the same exception).

However, I keep getting a "A Token was not found in the SecurityContext" when what I believe are bots are visiting certain pages (the referer is empty and the page is behind a firewall with anonymous = false).
When I go myself on the page, I am correctly redirected to the login page with no error showing up.

Any idea of how I could resolve that ?

Below my security.yml:

```
firewalls:
    dev:
        pattern:  ^/(_(profiler|wdt)|css|images|js)/
        security: false
    guest:
        pattern:        /(public/|$|genemu-captcha-refresh)
        anonymous:      true
        context:        main_auth
    main:
        pattern:        ^/
        anonymous:      false
        provider:       main
        context:        main_auth
        form_login:
            login_path: fos_user_security_login
            check_path: fos_user_security_check
        logout:
            path:       fos_user_security_logout
            target:     /
```

and my exception email with the trace:

```
    Une erreur s'est produite sur le site.

Date    08/03/2015 à 00:49:33
Utilisateur anonyme
Url courante    www.foodmeup.net/vote/flag/Post/le-lien-des-notifications-ne-marche-pas

Referer -
Url master  www.foodmeup.net/vote/flag/Post/le-lien-des-notifications-ne-marche-pas

Url parent  -
Code    0
Fichier /home/foodmeup.net/production/shared/vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Security/Http/Firewall/AccessListener.php
Ligne   53
Message A Token was not found in the SecurityContext.
Précédente erreur   aucune
Trace as string #0 /home/foodmeup.net/production/releases/20150307222736/app/cache/prod/classes.php(2940): Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall\AccessListener->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent))
#1 [internal function]: Symfony\Component\Security\Http\Firewall->onKernelRequest(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
#2 /home/foodmeup.net/production/releases/20150307222736/app/cache/prod/classes.php(2193): call_user_func(Array, Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent), 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher))
#3 /home/foodmeup.net/production/releases/20150307222736/app/cache/prod/classes.php(2126): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->doDispatch(Array, 'kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent))
#4 /home/foodmeup.net/production/releases/20150307222736/app/cache/prod/classes.php(2287): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\EventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent))
#5 /home/foodmeup.net/production/releases/20150307222736/app/bootstrap.php.cache(3011): Symfony\Component\EventDispatcher\ContainerAwareEventDispatcher->dispatch('kernel.request', Object(Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Event\GetResponseEvent))
#6 /home/foodmeup.net/production/releases/20150307222736/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2984): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handleRaw(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1)
#7 /home/foodmeup.net/production/releases/20150307222736/app/bootstrap.php.cache(3133): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\HttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#8 /home/foodmeup.net/production/releases/20150307222736/app/bootstrap.php.cache(2377): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\DependencyInjection\ContainerAwareHttpKernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request), 1, true)
#9 /home/foodmeup.net/production/releases/20150307222736/web/app.php(27): Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Kernel->handle(Object(Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request))
#10 {main}
```

Comment: I can of course not send the email when the token is empty, which I did in the meantime, but this is not helping me understand why it is empty...

Comment: Try a curl request and lets see if it's the same.

Comment: I'm don't know anything about curl, how would I do that?

Comment: Curl is a software for preforming diffrent type of requests over the network.

You can simulate any type of bot.

http://curl.haxx.se/docs/httpscripting.html#GET

You need to install it on your computer.